# Change HTML DOM while page loads

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to edit some node's content in DOM on the page, but if i do it using `window.onload` it's done only after the *full* page loaded and it is visible that the content of node changes.

So, is there a way to edit some node's content while page loading but before it's shown to user?

Comment: With a server-side language such as PHP you can but if you control the site you can edit the underlying html anyway so the reason you wish to do this is unclear.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I'm using a framework which I would like to do not edit, but to make some button's text a bit more beautiful I want to change its content before it's shown to user. But also I want to do not spend a lot of time for it and do it _while_ page loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can have `display: none;` for it and change it when the page is loaded. Like:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    let item = document.getElementById("myitem");
    item.innerText = "fully loaded";
    item.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    item.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#myitem {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myitem">loading...</div>
```

Just make sure that whatever you do not want to display yet has `display: none;` and you change that when it's appropriate, i.e., on page load.

Comment: Seems it works, but with large framework which takes about 1.5 second to load, your answer works same time as using `window.onload` :(

Comment: @complex yes, this is an unoptimized way to make things work. If you want to optimize it, you need to find some pattern and provide further information. Example: Do you want to have a "contains" search or a "starts with search"? If it is the latter, then we can already optimize it.

Comment: the only information I have is that button have CSS class `span.v-btn__content` and in HTML code looks like `<span class="v-btn__content">Some_content_with_underscores</span>`. In my hook I do (when found button using `querySelectorAll()`): `button.textContent = button.textContent.replace(/_/g, " ");`.

If there is a way to optimize this, it would be nice :)

Comment: @complex the problem is that you have a lot of possible values that need to be shown as previews. You need to provide more information on how those values look alike and how you want your search to work alike.